# How to convert a CSV file to JSON in Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, csv

Hello I'm consuming data from an API using Axios, the problem is that this data is in csv format and I'm trying to convert it to a JSON object.

I tried to use some js libraries but none of them worked with Vue

What can I do?

Example:

(This how the data is represented)

```
fecha,casos_total,casos_pcr,casos_test_ac,altas,fallecimientos,ingresos_uci,hospitalizados
2020-02-21,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-22,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-23,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-24,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-25,4,4,,,,,
```

(This is how I want to be displayed)

```js
[
  {
    "fecha": "2020-02-21",
    "casos_total": 3,
    "casos_pcr": 3,
    "casos_test_ac": "",
    "altas": "",
    "fallecimientos": "",
    "ingresos_uci": "",
    "hospitalizados": ""
  },
  {
    "fecha": "2020-02-22",
    "casos_total": 3,
    "casos_pcr": 3,
    "casos_test_ac": "",
    "altas": "",
    "fallecimientos": "",
    "ingresos_uci": "",
    "hospitalizados": ""
  },
  {
    "fecha": "2020-02-23",
    "casos_total": 3,
    "casos_pcr": 3,
    "casos_test_ac": "",
    "altas": "",
    "fallecimientos": "",
    "ingresos_uci": "",
    "hospitalizados": ""
  },
  {
    "fecha": "2020-02-24",
    "casos_total": 3,
    "casos_pcr": 3,
    "casos_test_ac": "",
    "altas": "",
    "fallecimientos": "",
    "ingresos_uci": "",
    "hospitalizados": ""
  },
  {
    "fecha": "2020-02-25",
    "casos_total": 4,
    "casos_pcr": 4,
    "casos_test_ac": "",
    "altas": "",
    "fallecimientos": "",
    "ingresos_uci": "",
    "hospitalizados": ""
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the input string by `\n` to get the individual lines.
2. Split the first line by `,` to get the headers.
3. Split the following lines by `,` to get the fields.
4. Join the headers and fields by index ([map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the headers into an array of header name and field name), and [create an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) from the result.

```js
const input = `fecha,casos_total,casos_pcr,casos_test_ac,altas,fallecimientos,ingresos_uci,hospitalizados
2020-02-21,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-22,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-23,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-24,3,3,,,,,
2020-02-25,4,4,,,,,`

const lines = input.split('\n') // 1️⃣
const header = lines[0].split(',') // 2️⃣
const output = lines.slice(1).map(line => {
  const fields = line.split(',') // 3️⃣
  return Object.fromEntries(header.map((h, i) => [h, fields[i]])) // 4️⃣
})

console.log(output)
```